# AngularJS transclude scope in directive with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

My goal is to have a directive, which I give contents to, and it repeats them X times. Just like ng-repeat, only I want to wrap it in other features such as limit toggle and extra elements outside the transcluded content.

For some reason, the transclusion has no access to the directive isolate scope, no matter what I try.

I've used the `transclude` function inside `link`, in several variations, to no avail. Here's a demo:

- [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XCmyanWvfmC25IhHoJzS?p=preview)

And here's the gist of the code:

```
app.directive('repeatContents', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      items: '=repeatContents',
      limit: '=repeatLimit'
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">' +
                  '<em>Outside transclude: {{item}}</em><br />' +
                  '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
              '</div>',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
      transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
        el.append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If you look at the plunkr, you will see that outside the transclusion `{{item}}` is available, but not inside. Regardless of the `link` function's contents which were supposed to take care of it. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I couldn't get what you're going for to work... but alternatively, I did get it to work without the transclude by just putting the other directive in the template... Here's the plunkr in case that's helpful at all https://plnkr.co/edit/v7oFnukZxHMEi3xasFmc?p=preview

Comment: That's okay if I only have one use-case, but in my uses I'll have to make a copy of this directive for every use-case I have which defeats the purpose of a directive

Answer (score 1):

`transclude:true` transcludes the content while keeping a reference to the scope where the content is transcluded from (In our case, `repeat-contents` will transclude `<other-directive other-item="item"></other-directive>` while keeping a reference to the outer scope. `item` is not defined in the outer scope and the fact that your isolated scope defines `item` is irrelevant to the outer scope.

If you just want to transclude the template without keeping a reference to it's original scope you can use the following diective instead of `ng-transclude`:

```
app.directive('customTransclude', function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transcludeFn){
            if(!transcludeFn){
                throw 'Illegal use of custom-transclude directive! No parent directive that requires transclusion was found';
            }

            transcludeFn(scope, function(clone){
                element.empty().append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and then in the template of your `repeat-contents` directive you can use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <em>Outside transclude: {{item}}</em><br/>
    <custom-transclude></custom-transclude>
</div>
```

Comment: I get that error thrown or else told that transcludeFn is not a function.

Comment: @casraf you still have to use `transclude:true` in your `repeatContents` directive. Only change `ng-transclude` to `custom-transclude`. Hee is a working plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/jl8veC?p=preview

Comment: It seems a little clearer to me when you take the "link" out of the repeatContents directive in the working demo above.  That demonstrates what is actually happening, and why you see the additional "Other item:" at the end.